# Umbraco learning resources?

Tags: .net, asp.net, content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco-blog

Hai all, I need to create a site in umbraco. Is there any good resource to learn Umbraco? I am new to CMS. which is the good learning sites?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I second the videos.  That and the training are the best ways to learn Umbraco IMO.

However, the Wiki has some great articles and some help getting started: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki

Check this out: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/getting-started-with-umbraco-what-is-next-after-you-install

Also, the http://our.umbraco.org/ community site has a forum with very helpful people willing to clear things up.

Many developers blog and have created some getting started resources:

http://www.nibble.be/?p=76

http://www.blogfodder.co.uk/2009/10/5/a-complete-newbies-guide-to-umbraco-cms

EDIT: The new Documentation section on Our Umbraco will be a great place to go for help in the future:

http://our.umbraco.org/documentation

Comment: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki This link isn't working

Answer (score 6):

I'd would agree, the videos are a great starting point, but even after watching them you need to really get in and get your hands dirty. Watching the videos will just give you an important taste of what it does.

First thing I did after watching the videos was take to a standard .net website I had already built and port it over to umbraco - tried to figure out how all the stuff you are used to doing (css files, images, links, custom controls etc) get done in the umbraco world. I'd say forcing yourself to convert one of your old sites will be more valuable experience then just creating a brand new one for the first time in Umbraco. It forces you to realize how the way you used to do it, is now different.

After converting a pre-existing website to Umbraco, I created a brand new one the "umbraco" way from the start, and the experience of doing that first conversion was invaluable to help you understand not just *how* to do something in Umbraco, but why it needs to be done that way.

Answer (score 2):

The Umbraco website itself offers documentation, community and paid for video tutorials, which help to fund the ongoing development of the product.

http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Yup the umbraco web site is you best starting point, the videos are ver good - there is (I believe) a free trial period, also the actual cost is pretty nominal once you are passed the trial period. There are also week end course run from time to time - I know a couple of people who have done them and feel they are very worth while. There is a link to a forum as well on the web site.