# Up To Date Umbraco Learning Resources

Tags: umbraco

I am currently trying to learn the basics and theory behind Umbraco. After researching for hours for tutorials/documentation, I can't say I have come across anything particularly useful.

I have been able to set up a simple site using [this guide](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Using-Umbraco/Creating-Basic-Site/) but my main stumbling block is the concepts and terminology used within Umbraco - I am having difficulty finding information regarding plugins/widgets/add-ons/whatever name is used within umbraco - reusable dynamic content.

In my research, I have come across various video tutorials (from the Umbraco site itself), questions and blogs. However, most (if not all) of these are from pre-2011 and prove difficult to follow when using the latest Umbraco release. It also must be said that I have found myself being sent to a non-existent page on the [Umbraco community site](http://our.umbraco.org/) on more than one occasion, which is starting to become frustrating.

So my question - are there any up to date resources/tutorials that I can use to learn about Umbraco which go further than simply installing and adding a page?

Edit: this question is very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089173/umbraco-learning-resources) which was last updated in 2011 and most likely refer to pre-MVC days.

Comment: I apologize that this question seems to be off-topic, but I based it on the question linked in the edit, which prompted useful answers for that period in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you come across Umbraco.TV?

http://umbraco.tv/

Lots of useful video tutorials - however there is small subscription cost for the majority of the content.

Comment: I did, but I wasn't aware that there was some up to date content available at no cost - perfect for somebody trying to see if Umbraco is for them. Thank you.